# Problem with Java Swing Label and Button Outliners/ Positioning and Intellij Swing UI Designer

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, positioning

[image]

I am new to this forum and I have a question. I have to do programming work for university and as well as the `upperLabel`, as the button in the bottom are not centralized as you can see in the picture. I used the Intellij Swing UI Designer for help, but I think this created the problem. Do you have an idea or a line/ lines of code which I can extend?

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

private JLabel upperLabel;
private JPanel textArea;
private JLabel lowerLabel;
private JButton verstandenButton;
private JPanel mainPanel;
//private JLabel imageLabel;
private ArrayList<String> upperList;// = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> lowerList;
private int i = 0;
private int xPos[];
private int yPos[];

public void setLowerLabel(JLabel lowerLabel) {
    this.lowerLabel = lowerLabel;
}

public void setUpperLabel(JLabel upperLabel) {
    this.upperLabel = upperLabel;
}

public MyFrame() {
    int[] a = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
    int[] b = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
    MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame(a, b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
}

public MyFrame(int[] xPos, int[] yPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    toFront();
    setArrayLists();
    setSize(400, 600);
    // upperLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 5, 1, 1, Color.red));
    upperLabel.setText(upperList.get(i));
    lowerLabel.setText(lowerList.get(i));
    i++;
    setLocation(xPos[i], yPos[i]);
    upperLabel.setSize(400, 100);
    lowerLabel.setSize(400, 100);
    verstandenButton.setSize(400, 100);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setContentPane(mainPanel);
    setTitle("Test");
    setSize(500, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    upperLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 18));
    lowerLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 18));
    verstandenButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 18));

    verstandenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (i < 5) {
                upperLabel.setText(upperList.get(i));
                lowerLabel.setText(lowerList.get(i));

                //Position
                i++;
                setLocation(xPos[i], yPos[i]);
                // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "Confirmed");
                // JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
            } else {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
    //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/pfeil1.png");
    //imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
    //imageLabel.setText(icon);
    // ImageIcon icon = createImage("/images/pfeil1.png");

    //pack();
    setVisible(true);
}


public void setArrayLists() {
    upperList = new ArrayList<String>();
    upperList.add("Lorem Ipsum");
    upperList.add("Lorem Ipsum");
    upperList.add("Lorem Ipsum");
    upperList.add("Lorem Ipsum");
    upperList.add("Lorem Ipsum");


    lowerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    lowerList.add("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</html>");
    lowerList.add("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</html>");
    lowerList.add("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</html>");
    lowerList.add("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</html>");
    lowerList.add("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</html>");
}
   { $$$setupUI$$$(); }
/**
 * Method generated by IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer
 * >>> IMPORTANT!! <<<
 * DO NOT edit this method OR call it in your code!
 *
 * @noinspection ALL
 */
private void $$$setupUI$$$() {
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(2, 1, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
    mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(-9868951));
    mainPanel.setForeground(new Color(-14146117));
    mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    mainPanel.setToolTipText("sdsdsdsd");
    mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15), "", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.BELOW_TOP, null, null));
    upperLabel = new JLabel();
    Font upperLabelFont = this.$$$getFont$$$(null, -1, -1, upperLabel.getFont());
    if (upperLabelFont != null) upperLabel.setFont(upperLabelFont);
    upperLabel.setForeground(new Color(-1));
    upperLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
    upperLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(0);
    upperLabel.setText("Muster");
    mainPanel.add(upperLabel, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_NONE, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, new Dimension(400, -1), new Dimension(400, 100), 0, false));
    textArea = new JPanel();
    textArea.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(2, 2, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
    textArea.setBackground(new Color(-9868951));
    textArea.setForeground(new Color(-1));
    textArea.setToolTipText("");
    mainPanel.add(textArea, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, null, null, null, 0, false));
    verstandenButton = new JButton();
    verstandenButton.setBackground(new Color(-14146117));
    verstandenButton.setEnabled(true);
    Font verstandenButtonFont = this.$$$getFont$$$(null, -1, -1, verstandenButton.getFont());
    if (verstandenButtonFont != null) verstandenButton.setFont(verstandenButtonFont);
    verstandenButton.setForeground(new Color(-1));
    verstandenButton.setText("Verstanden!");
    verstandenButton.putClientProperty("hideActionText", Boolean.FALSE);
    textArea.add(verstandenButton, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 0, 1, 2, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_HORIZONTAL, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, new Dimension(600, -1), null, 0, false));
    final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(2, 2, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
    panel1.setBackground(new Color(-9868951));
    textArea.add(panel1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 2, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, null, null, null, 0, false));
    lowerLabel = new JLabel();
    Font lowerLabelFont = this.$$$getFont$$$(null, -1, -1, lowerLabel.getFont());
    if (lowerLabelFont != null) lowerLabel.setFont(lowerLabelFont);
    lowerLabel.setForeground(new Color(-1));
    lowerLabel.setText("Muster");
    panel1.add(lowerLabel, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_WEST, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_NONE, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, null, null, new Dimension(400, -1), 0, false));
    final com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer spacer1 = new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer();
    panel1.add(spacer1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_HORIZONTAL, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, 1, null, null, null, 0, false));
    final com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer spacer2 = new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.Spacer();
    panel1.add(spacer2, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_VERTICAL, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, null, null, null, 0, false));
}

/**
 * @noinspection ALL
 */
private Font $$$getFont$$$(String fontName, int style, int size, Font currentFont) {
    if (currentFont == null) return null;
    String resultName;
    if (fontName == null) {
        resultName = currentFont.getName();
    } else {
        Font testFont = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 10);
        if (testFont.canDisplay('a') && testFont.canDisplay('1')) {
            resultName = fontName;
        } else {
            resultName = currentFont.getName();
        }
    }
    Font font = new Font(resultName, style >= 0 ? style : currentFont.getStyle(), size >= 0 ? size : currentFont.getSize());
    boolean isMac = System.getProperty("os.name", "").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).startsWith("mac");
    Font fontWithFallback = isMac ? new Font(font.getFamily(), font.getStyle(), font.getSize()) : new StyleContext().getFont(font.getFamily(), font.getStyle(), font.getSize());
    return fontWithFallback instanceof FontUIResource ? fontWithFallback : new FontUIResource(fontWithFallback);
}

/**
 * @noinspection ALL
 */
public JComponent $$$getRootComponent$$$() {
    return mainPanel;
}
}
```

Comment: `DO NOT edit this method OR call it in your code!` Learn how to layout components using layout managers. At the moment, you are not using the IDE so much as it is using you.

Comment: Do not add things like `SOLVED` to your question title. If you managed to solve your problem, then either accept the answer that helped you solve it, or - as in this case - if there is no answer, post your own answer and accept it after the timeout.